# Как определить обращение сторонней программы к ID жесткогоДиска\мат.Платы и скрыть/подменить результат?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, железо, прерывания

Как понимаю, возможно, нужно сканировать прерывания, что бы определить обращается ли процесс программы именно к месту хранения ID диска/платы?

с драйверами делать ничго не нужно?

каков алгоритм решения данной задачи, какие языки и средства лучше использовать?

+

Вот, для начала нашел с чем разобраться:

http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=512189&msg=5125145

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/mcpp/driveinfoex.aspx

https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/104263#comment-109719

https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/general/article.php/c11627/Trace-RPC-Calls-and-Notify-the-COM-Events-to-Your-Program.htm - что-то на подобие того для ловли обращения к айдишкам.

пример перехвата обращений внешней ппроги к чему-то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935745/is-it-possible-to-intercept-calls-to-console-from-another-process

Comment: Какая операционка?

Comment: прерывания тут точно не причем. id читаются без всяких прерываний. Все зависит только от того, что это за программа. В современных ОС обычные программы не могут обращаться к оборудованию напрямую, а делают это через драйвера. значит для такого случая достаточно перехватить точку входа в функцию драйвера, отвечающую за нужную информацию. Если программам в вашей ОС можно обращаться напрямую, но она все таки не в 0 кольце защиты, то можно запретить ей ввод-вывод и эмулировать обращения к любому оборудованию своими силами. Если же программа получила реальное 0 кольцо - то перехватить невозможно

Comment: @Mike спасибо. а если программа обращается через драйвер, как определить какой и как можно запретить ввод-вывод и эмулировать обращения к оборудованию ? как это все делать?

Comment: для начала найдите программу, которая это делает. посмотрите какие средства она использует. посмотрите документацию на используемую ОС. Что касается эмулятора, то вы только что спросили "как написать свой эмулятор, типа VMWare", невозможно вкратце рассказать, что должны делать десятки тысяч строк кода эмулятора. И тут все зависит не только то ОС, но и от используемого процессора. На каждом процессоре могут быть свои методы. Изучайте документацию на требуемый процессор

Comment: Хотя нет, вкратце можно: для процессоров архитектуры intel выставляете поле iopl в регистре флагов программы равным нулю. при возникновении нарушения общей защиты дизассемблируете инструкцию, вызвавшую исключение, если она обращается к тем регистрам, которые отвечают за требуемые параметры, кладете в целевой регистр (в сохраненную в TSS копию конечно) инструкции требуемое значение. в остальных случаях выполняете инструкцию самостоятельно и кладете результаты в целевой регистр, возвращаете управление программе на инстукцию, следующую за вызвавшей исключение

Comment: Если Windows, то посмотрите в сторону Hooks. Даже обращение к драйверами идёт через WinAPI. Также существуют ограничения. Скорее всего, без жёсткого опхода проблем доступа к защищённым частям программ не обойтись, а это означает хорошее знание ОС.

Comment: спасибо за тветы!! точно увидел, что много предстоит подучить, что бы то сделать. если у кого будут еще ссылки, примеры кода и др. по этому делу - буду благодарен!